# How to programatically add line break to a paragraph tag

Tags: javascript, html, whitespace, line-breaks

I want to apply a line break to a dom element programatically.

I have tried to used `<br>`, `<br/>` and `\n` from different answers of solving this problem.

However, none of them work.

Here is an example:

```js
document.getElementById('1').textContent = "\n".repeat(6)
document.getElementById('2').textContent = "<br/>".repeat(6)
```

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h2>Set <code>\n</code></h2>
<p id="1"></p>

<h2>Set <code>&lt;br/&gt;</code></h2>
<p id="2"></p>
```

The `<br>`, `<br/>` will appear in the `textContent`, but doesn't apply the line break.

The `\n` doesn't appear in the `textContent`, and also doesn't apply the line break.

Do anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) will escape the values you pass - you should set [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) instead

Comment: You cannot use "textContent". You have to use: result.innerHTML += arr[i] + "<br />";

Comment: @KyleMit Got it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Encoding

- [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) will escape the values you pass.
- [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) will perserve the string as html

### Whitespace

`\n` will add a new line, but since html is whitepsace agnostic, it won't show up by default inside of a `<p>` tag.  If you want to add line breaks, you can use `<br/>` instead

### Demo in Stack Snippets

```js
document.getElementById('1').textContent = "<br/>".repeat(6)
document.getElementById('2').innerHTML = "<br/>".repeat(6)
```

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h2>Set <code>textContent</code></h2>
<p id="1"></p>

<h2>Set <code>innerHTML</code></h2>
<p id="2"></p>
```

Comment: I just wonder what is the purpose of using `<br/>\n` instead of just simply using `<br/>`

Comment: Updated - you're probably looking for `<br/>` if you'd like to add new lines to your paragraph